# PostGIS ST_Contains / ST_Intersect with one point envelope

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, extents, st-intersects

With PostGIS I have to test wether a point is inside an envelope or not. Sometimes the envelope is constructed from a point and a few others next to it, and sometimes only from a single point, against which I'm testing the intersection.

In that special case, the test fail. It case easily be reproduced with this query:

```
Select ST_Intersects(
    ST_MakeEnvelope(10, 4, 10, 4),
    ST_MakePoint(10, 4)
);
```

-> returns false, should return true

If I just change one of the 4 envelope delimiters, it works:

```
Select ST_Intersects(
    ST_MakeEnvelope(10, 4, 10, 4.1),
    ST_MakePoint(10, 4)
);
```

-> returns true as expected

ST_Contains behaves the same.

Is there a function that would work in my case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you are facing is geometric validity: the resulting *Polygon* geometry of an `ST_MakeEnvelope` of a *Point* (i.e. when used with the same coordinates) is **invalid**, and all relationship functions **then short circuit to `false`**.

`ST_Extent` returns a *bounding box* (`BOX3D` data type), for which these functions resolve in simple min-max comparisons without geometric validity check.

Compare to using the `&&` *bounding box* intersection operator:

```
SELECT 'POINT(10 4)'::GEOMETRY && ST_MakeEnvelope(10, 4, 10, 4);

 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

returning equal results in cases when comparing against rectangular *bounding boxes*.

In fact, if you are going to only ever compare to rectangular *Polygon*s, **using `&&` is faster** - you can either pre-group with `ST_Collect`, or use `ST_Extent` as you did in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why my original request returned true. It should throw an error IMHO, returning false is extremely error prone...! Using && seems to do the job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found a hack a few seconds after posting... Here we go:

```
select ST_Intersects(
    ST_Extent(ST_MakeEnvelope(10, 4, 10, 4)),
    ST_MakePoint(10, 4)
);
```

Not sure why this work and not the original request...

EDIT: ST_Extent being an aggregate function, I had to wrap it in a subquery. In the end the query looks like this:

```
select
    title
from
    route,
    ( select ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(ST_MakeEnvelope(10, 4, 10, 4)), 4326) as bbox) as sub
where
    ST_Intersects(sub.bbox, ST_StartPoint(ST_GeometryN(points, 1)) );
```